# Warning: Multiple merge bases detected. Simple situation. How did this happen?

Tags: git, azure, pull-request

I did a fresh pull from my remote develop branch.  I created a new branch from develop.  Made some changes, committed, pushed.  Created a pull request in Azure.

Now, I'm getting that warning.  How can that happen?  This is about as straightforward as can be.

Answer (score 0):

(slaps forehead)

I accidentally created my pull request against the master branch, instead of the develop branch.  I make this mistake fairly regularly.  More often, when I wasn't the one handling the pull requests from the other side.

Just wanted this answer out there, because I'm sure I'm not the only one doing this.